# DBATools.io - Copy-DbaLogin - unable to copy logins for AAD Groups

Tags: sql-server, dbatools, copy-dbalogin, azure-managed-instance

We are wanting to copy all the Logins from one Azure Managed Instance to another. We are using the DBATools.io powershell command "Copy-DbaLogin" to do this. We are using the -Force option to drop & recreate any logins already in place on the target instance. This command works great for SQL auth logins.

However for logins that represent Azure Active Directory Groups, it fails part way through (meaning it drops the login from the target server, but then fails to recreate it again based on what is present on the source server).

The error message is "Cannot find the login 'MyGroupName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

I don't recall ever having this problem in the past -- but then again this is the first time I'm using the command against Azure Managed Instances rather than normal SQL Servers.

UPDATE: I have now checked and can confirm that the message occurs regardless of whether I am using SQL auth or AAD with MFA to connect to the Managed Instance. So this does seem to be more of a problem with DBATools than an Azure issue.

Anyone know the cause?